How to schedule git maintenance on a cron schedule?
Git maintenance  have register command to schedule maintenance tasks.
How can I schedule gc task with a cron schedule?

background on why maintenance is a must in my project:  We have large mono repos which we are maintaining in containers to be used by various services.  If we run git gc, it almost always errors out saying some other git process is running, cannot continue.  But git maintenance --task=gc works well.    but I have to run it manually.  Scheduling it would be a great option!

Reason for asking it here is because git maintenance is a fairly new feature (compared to others) and the documentation contains no examples on scheduling.


You don't need git maintenance register gc.
You can write a simple cron job which execute
AS you mentioned in the comments you prefer git maintenance

0 * * * * cd /path/to/your/repo && git maintenance run --task=gc

